# which antivirus is best for my laptop?

Tags: antivirus, protection

I want to buy a antivirus for my laptop.but I am in a fix.I want to buy such a antivirus that doesn't slow my laptop much.laptop configaration :processor core i5,Ram 4GB,operating system windows 7।please suggest me some best antiviruses.
..

Comment: Hi FRM - please read the help page to understand what is in scope for this site. Recommending an antivirus isn't. Use any one you want, or read one of the many a/v reviews online.

Answer (score 1):

Your brain! Anti viruses are known to be useless in most cases. Read [this](http://www.cbc.ca/news/technology/malware-threats-making-anti-virus-software-totally-useless-1.2559432) to know why.

Other than your brain you may want to use basic Anti virus for your daily usage. I personally prefer **Kaspersky** or **NOD32**. Have a look at [this](http://www.av-comparatives.org/dynamic-tests/) independent report and statistics and decide for yourself.

Comment: AV is not 'useless' - it has limitations. If nothing else, AV helps protect against the 'background radiation' of the internet, which is of value.

Comment: @schroeder It was a bit sarcastic to be honest. AVs are definitely not totally useless, but if you're target by an advanced malware (rootkits) they AVs are pretty much useless :)